# Modifying the immutable class instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, immutability

I've got a somewhat complex data-type `Mask` that I'd like to be able to use fast identity checking for such as:

```
seen = set()
m = Mask(...)
if m in seen:
    ...
```

This suggests that Mask should be *hashable* and therefore *immutable*. However, I'd like to generate variants of `m` and `Mask` seems like the place to encapsulate the variation logic. Here is a minimalish example that demonstrates what I want to accomplish:

```
class Mask(object):
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.seq = seq
        self.hash = reduce(lambda x, y: x ^ y, self.seq)

    # __hash__ and __cmp__ satisfy the hashable contract §3.4.1)
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.hash

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.seq, other.seq)

    def complement(self):
        # cannot modify self without violating immutability requirement
        # so return a new instance instead
        return Mask([-x for x in self.seq])
```

This satisfies all of the hashable and immutable properties. The peculiarity is having what is effectively a Factory method `complement`; is this a reasonable way to implement the desired function? Note that I am **not** at all interested in protecting against "malicious" modification as many related questions on SO are looking to achieve.

As this example is intentionally small it could be trivially solved by making a tuple of seq. The type that I am actually working with does not afford such simple casting.

Comment: Is this code correct, and you're just wondering about style (or if there's a better way to achieve the same result)?

Comment: @MattBall yes, the code is correct and it is a style or "Pythonic" question.

Comment: Note that XORing a bunch of numbers together does not make for a very good hash function as all permutations of a sequence will have the same hash value.

Comment: you could use `hash(self.seq)` as a hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using immutable types, all 'variation' methods must return new objects/instances, and thus be factories in that sense.

Many languages make strings immutable (including Python). So all string operations return new strings; `strB = strA.replace(...)` etc.

If you could change the instance at all, it wouldn't be immutable.

Edit:

Rereading, you're asking if this is reasonable, and I say yes. The logic would not be better put somewhere else, and as I pointed out with string immutability it is a common paradigm to get new variations from existing ones.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of string modification as analogous; thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is pretty much how you write an immutable class; methods that would otherwise change an object's state become, in your terms, "factories" that create new instances.

Note that in the specific case of computing a complement, you can name the method `__invert__` and use it as

```
inv_mask = ~mask
```

Operator syntax is a strong signal to client code that operations return new values of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't inforce immutability. It is up to you to make sure that objects are not modified while they are in a `set`. Otherwise you don't need immutability to use sets, dictionaries in Python.